# cannot modify legend attributes in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, label, legend

I am trying to modify the color, labels and breaks on the legend of this plot, but the scale_xxx_yyyy options won't work. Any suggestions?

My input is like this:

```
     GENE CHR       POS        key        value      LOGP
1   A1BG  19  58862834 MAF1P-pval 0.6456014613 0.1900355
2   A1CF  10  52566602 MAF1P-pval 0.0005533904 3.2569684
3    A2M  12   9225025 MAF1P-pval 0.6912238768 0.1603813
4  A2ML1  12   8975786 MAF1P-pval 0.6855731854 0.1639462
5 A4GALT  22  43089044 MAF1P-pval 0.3471331356 0.4595039
6  A4GNT   3 137843236 MAF1P-pval 0.6070832685 0.2167517
....
31205  ZBTB12   6  31868446 CADD20-pval 0.43193898 0.36457760
31206 ZCCHC24  10  81154122 CADD20-pval 0.01495022 1.82535253
31207 ZDHHC21   9  14619044 CADD20-pval 0.79231233 0.10110358
31208 ZMYND19   9 140477032 CADD20-pval 0.89922171 0.04613322
31209  ZNF710  15  90611241 CADD20-pval 0.07090869 1.14930051
31210  ZYG11B   1  53222142 CADD20-pval 0.27036413 0.56805093
```

The variable key is coded as factor.
and I have generated the following plot using the code:

```
ggplot(merge3, aes(x=POS, y=LOGP, color=Key)) + geom_point(size=0.3) + 
facet_grid(~CHR, switch="x", scales="free_x") + 
theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), panel.spacing.x=unit(0.001, "lines"), panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank(), strip.background=element_rect(fill="white")) + 
labs(title="stacked Manhattan MAF1P, CADD20", y="-log10(p)", x= "chromosome") + 
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,12), expand = c(0,0)) + 
geom_hline(yintercept=5.3, color = "red") + 
geom_hline(yintercept=3.3, color = "blue")
```

Manhattan plot combining two datasets
[image: Manhattan plot combining two datasets]

Now, I try to modify different aspects of the legend, like color, title, labels or breaks using:

```
bp + scale_x_discrete(limits=c("MAF1"<="1%","CADD">="20"))
bp + scale_fill_discrete(name="Gene Sets", breaks=c("MAF <= 1%","CADD >=20"), labels=c("MAF1"<="1%","CADD">="20"))
bp + scale_fill_manual(values = c("#d8b365", "#f5f5f5"))
```

But none of these work, I have only managed to change legend title by using:

```
bp + labs(colour="Gene Sets")
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated

Comment: I see a couple of ideas that might help.  First, you mapped to `color` and not `fill`.  Since this is a discrete value try `scale_color_manual()` or `scale_color_discrete()`.  Second, the `POS` variable you used for `x` looks continuous to me and not discrete, which might account for why `scale_x_discrete()` isn't working for you.

Comment: Hi aosmith!
the ```scale_color_manual()``` worked!!! THANKS!!!
But unfortunately not the scale_x_discrete() after modifying POS from continuous to discrete.
I guess my last resort is to change the description of the key variable and its levels in the dataframe

Comment: Why do u need x to be discrete? It's the position of the gene right? or you want to change the order of the legends, like have MAF before CADD

Comment: @StupidWolf yes you are right, I want to be able to change the order of the legend, as well as its content to be able to introduce special characters like <=

Comment: @StupidWolf
Thanks for your recommendations below, those worked great. 
And yes, the key vs Key was a typo, my bad, when I was introducing the code above

Comment: Hi @VictoriaFernandez, no problem. Was just wondering whether the data used might have been different. Ok glad it worked for you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you are using "Key" in your code, whereas the input data you showed has "key".

First we simulate some data that looks like yours:

```
library(TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene)
g = genes(TxDb.Hsapiens.UCSC.hg19.knownGene)
g = g[seqnames(g) %in% seqlevels(g)[1:24]]
seqlevels(g) = sub("chr","",seqlevels(g))

merge3 = data.frame(GENE=rep(g$gene_id,2),
CHR=rep(as.character(seqnames(g)),2),
POS=rep(start(g),2),
LOGP=-log10(runif(length(g)*2)),
Key = rep(c("MAF1P-pval","CADD20-pval"),each=length(g))
)
merge3$CHR = factor(merge3$CHR,levels=seqlevels(g)[1:24])
head(merge3)

       GENE CHR       POS       LOGP        Key
1         1  19  58858172 0.04981794 MAF1P-pval
2        10   8  18248755 1.83126403 MAF1P-pval
3       100  20  43248163 0.46686285 MAF1P-pval
4      1000  18  25530930 0.96742037 MAF1P-pval
5     10000   1 243651535 0.31012565 MAF1P-pval
6 100008586   X  49217763 0.61290850 MAF1P-pval
```

Then we plot:

```
bp = ggplot(merge3, aes(x=POS, y=LOGP, color=Key)) + geom_point(size=0.3) + 
facet_grid(~CHR, switch="x", scales="free_x") + 
theme(axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), panel.spacing.x=unit(0.001, "lines"), panel.grid = element_blank(), panel.border = element_blank(), strip.background=element_rect(fill="white")) + 
labs(title="stacked Manhattan MAF1P, CADD20", y="-log10(p)", x= "chromosome") + 
scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,12), expand = c(0,0)) + 
geom_hline(yintercept=5.3, color = "red") + 
geom_hline(yintercept=3.3, color = "blue")
```

The last part to modify your legend, so your keys are sorted alphabetically, to make it less confusing, set the colors first:

```
COLS=c("#d8b365", "#f5f5f5")
names(COLS) = levels(merge3$Key)
```

Then we use breaks to reverse the order and give labels:

```
bp+scale_color_manual(name="Gene Sets",values = COLS,
breaks = rev(names(COLS)),labels=c("MAF <= 1%","CADD >=20"))
```